# Eclipse is not picking up the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable resulting in handshake failure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have set the environment variable (windows) for MAVEN_OPTS, including references to my keystore, truststore etc, and when I build my maven project from the command line it works without any issues.

My problem is that Eclipse doesn't seem to be picking up MAVEN_OPTS as it won't build the same project. Which I could resolve by adding explicitly the MAVEN_OPTS parameters to the Maven goal within eclipse. But this doesn't solve my Eclipse project showing as having errors by (I assume) a Maven plugin in Eclipse.

This is the error:

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer
>   artifact antlr:antlr:pom:2.7.6 from/to internal-repository
>   (https://"hostname"/artifactory/repo): java.net.ConnectException:
>   Received fatal alert: handshake_failure to
>   https://"hostname"/artifactory/repo/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.pom

Where I have replaced the actual hostname for "hostname" for the purposes of this question.

Could someone please help me fix this problem as I would like to have Eclipse showing without any errors.

Thanks!

Edit: I have updated maven to the latest version 3.0.4 and the issue remains but with a different error:

> Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to
>   internal-repository (https://"hostname"/artifactory/repo):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Update:
I can now build by adding the remote repository certificate to the default java keystore but I can't get rid of the problems shown on my eclipse projects. I have tried adding the MAVEN OPTS parameters to eclipse.ini without any luck.

Comment: did you restart eclipse after setting the env var? i think eclipse loads system variable on startup

Comment: yep - restarted eclipse.